# Numpy.unique fails when used after .append

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I have a small function that extracts grayscale values from an image and scales them down to even divisions between 0 and 1. The function:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import math

def get_binary(I):
    Bin = []
    unique_vals = np.unique(I)
    print(unique_vals)
    for y in range(I.size[1]):
        c = []
        for x in range(I.size[0]):
            for n in range(len(unique_vals)):
                val = I.getpixel((x,y))
                if val == 0 or val == (0,0,0):
                    c.append(0)
                elif val == unique_vals[n]:
                    c.append(1/(len(unique_vals)-1)*n)

        Bin.append(c)
    #print(len(np.unique(c)))
    #print(np.shape(Bin))
    #print(len(np.unique(Bin)))
    return Bin

img = Image.open('Si_Al_Combo.png')
get_binary(img)
```

It relies on the numpy.unique() method to determine what values are present in the image and what value between 0 and 1 they will become. In my test case, my image has 3 values (0, 127, 255) which are changed to 0, 0.5, and 1.0, respectively, so `print(len(np.unique(c)))` should (and does) output 3, but `print(len(np.unique(Bin)))` seems to interpret each individual value in `Bin` as unique, which they're not and nor should they be. What's happening?

Edit: here is the image I used to test this function
[image: A grayscale image with only three values: 0, 127, 255]

Comment: "seems to interpret each individual value in Bin as unique" <- this isn't entirely clear. Can you show exactly what values you're getting, and say what you were expecting instead? Also, did you read the bit in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) that states "Input array. Unless axis is specified, this will be flattened if it is not already 1-D."? (But note that the `axis` argument is only available in Numpy >= 1.13.)

Comment: `print(len(np.unique(c)))` gives `3` while `print(len(np.unique(Bin)))` gives `236`, which matches the output of `print(np.shape(Bin))`, which is `(236,)`. I was expecting the `np.unique(Bin)` to output `3` to match `np.unique(c)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a ragged list of lists to `np.unique`: that is, you're passing a list of lists of numbers, but the inner lists don't all have the same length. That means that when `np.unique` [tries to convert its input to an array](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/e94ed84010c60961f82860d146681d3fd607de4e/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L208) (which is the very first thing it does), it ends up with a one-dimensional array of dtype `object`, in which each element is a Python list containing one row of your transformed image.

So then `np.unique` goes on to find the number of distinct *sublists*, rather than the number of distinct *values* from all the sublists collected together.

If your input list of lists *weren't* ragged, this wouldn't happen: `np.unique` would convert to a 2d array of numbers, and then without an `axis` argument, would flatten before finding unique values.

Here's a demonstration on a smaller array: first, with a ragged list of lists:

```
>>> x = [[1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 0, 2], [2, 3, 4]]
>>> np.asanyarray(x)  # this is what ends up being analysed by np.unique
array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([0, 1, 0, 2]), list([2, 3, 4])], dtype=object)
>>> np.unique(x)
array([list([0, 1, 0, 2]), list([1, 2, 3]), list([2, 3, 4])], dtype=object)
```

and then in the case where all sublists have the same length:

```
>>> x = [[1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1]]
>>> np.asanyarray(x)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 2],
       [2, 2, 1]])
>>> np.unique(x)
array([1, 2, 3])
```

It looks as though the fact that you have a ragged list of lists in the first place is a bug in your code, and is due to appending `0` more times that you intended to. Note that if `I.getpixel((x,y))` is `0`, you end up appending `0` to `c` on *every* iteration of the inner loop. That is, I suspect that your inner loop should look something like this:

```
val = I.getpixel((x, y))
if val == 0 or val == (0,0,0):
    c.append(0)
else:
    for n in range(len(unique_vals)):
        if val == unique_vals[n]:
            c.append(1/(len(unique_vals)-1)*n)
```

By the way, you might also want to look into the `return_inverse` argument to [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html). If you have your original image available as an array, this essentially does all the work that you need for your conversion. Here's a toy example, with a tiny shape `(4, 3)` input image:

```
>>> x = np.array([[0, 127, 127], [127, 255, 0], [255, 127, 0], [0, 0, 255]])
>>> x
array([[  0, 127, 127],
       [127, 255,   0],
       [255, 127,   0],
       [  0,   0, 255]])
>>> unique_vals, inverse = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
>>> inverse  # the inverse comes back flattened, so restore the shape
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2])
>>> inverse.reshape(x.shape)
array([[0, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 0],
       [2, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 2]])
>>> inverse.reshape(x.shape) / (len(unique_vals) - 1.)
array([[0. , 0.5, 0.5],
       [0.5, 1. , 0. ],
       [1. , 0.5, 0. ],
       [0. , 0. , 1. ]])
```

Look Ma, no for loops!

Comment: This is a really good explanation. Thank you for providing this insight, I never would've intuited that `np.unique` was compiling a list of lists instead of values. The fix you gave at the end worked perfectly- you're right that there's probably a better way to do the loop but fancy footwork can come after proof of concept. Thanks again

Comment: Just saw your edit for `return_inverse`. Fancy! I'll have to give that a try